# Unexpected reserved word 'await' in async function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im really new in React and I want to get location coordinates and pass them to API with parameters, but I receive:

```
 Unexpected reserved word 'await'
```

The code:

```
  async getData() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
    console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
    console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=ca148f5dc67f12aafaa56d1878bb6db2`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json();
    
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

}

Comment: you can only use await inside an `async` function - look very carefully which function you use `await` in ... and remember, `async` is not "inherited"

Comment: `watchPosition(function` the function given to `watchPosition` needs to be async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function needs to be `async`. You did make the parent function async but then you are also passing in a callback which you didn't make asynchronous

```js
  async getData() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(async function (position) {
    console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
    console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;

    const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=ca148f5dc67f12aafaa56d1878bb6db2`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json();
    
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: There's a bigger problem here: `watchPosition` doesn't set up a one-off callback.

Answer (score 2):

Your `await` isn't in an `async` function (it's in a non-`async` function nested in an `async` function), but the bigger problem is that your `getData` is trying to return a promise for something that doesn't fit the promise model: a **repeated** series of updates from the geolocation object. [`watchPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) calls its callback repeatedly, not just once.

JavaScript doesn't have inbuilt semantics for this kind of thing, which is generally called an "observable" (well, there are `async` iterators, but I suspect you probably don't want that). There are libraries for it, but otherwise you'll have to have `getData` accept a callback that will get called whenever there's an update. Something along the lines of:

```
getData(callback) {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        throw new Error("No geolocation available");
    }
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
        console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
        console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon = position.coords.longitude;

        const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=ca148f5dc67f12aafaa56d1878bb6db2`;
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(result => {
            try {
                callback(result);
            } catch { }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // ...perhaps handle the error or similar...
        });
    });
}
```

From the name `getData`, you may have meant just to get the current location as a one-off. That's the [`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) method. If so, you'll need to create a promise manually since `getCurrentPosition` doesn't provide one:

```
getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!navigator.geolocation) {
            reject(new Error("No geolocation available"));
            return;
        }
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
            console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);

            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;

            const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=ca148f5dc67f12aafaa56d1878bb6db2`;
            resolve(
                fetch(url)
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
                    }
                    return response.json();
                })
            );
        });
    });
}
```

But that's only if you want just the current location.